# Chatbase no Sessionflow visible

Tags: chatbase

I'm facing issues to get sessionflows on my chatbase account.

I'm sending these data as stated by the doc :

```
        {
            api_key: "xxx", 
            type: "user",
            platform: "xxx",
            message: "xxx",
            intent: "myIntent",
            version: "1.0",
            user_id: "xxx",
            time_stamp: new Date().getTime(),
        }
```

I don't specify the session_id as it should be infered automatically.

I made some conversations with "chained" intents like "**search.recipe**", "**search.recipe-yes**", "**search.recipe-yes-steps**", "**search.recipe-yes-steps-next**" "**search.recipe-yes-steps-previous**" "**search.recipe-yes-steps-repeat**" that, if i understood the doc correctly, should generate a proper session flow.
The doc isn't quite clear about the "dash" separator, nothing states clearly if anything else than a dash can be used or not for example. But the examples use that dash and so i did.

Still, the session flow tab shows nothing, even after days *(should be a 6 hours max delay if i'm not mistaken)*.

I have data in the handled and not handled messages so my API calls are working properly, but nothing in the sessionflow tab...

Any hint on what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am Sean with Chatbase support.  We identified a bug during the processing of messages for the Session Flow report which was the likely cause of the delay you are experiencing.  The messages are currently being reprocessed and should be available shortly.
Regarding your question about the chained, or sub-intents, there are no restrictions on using a '.' or '-' character as a separator.  If you are 
still unable to view your Session Flow, please contact us via our [feedback form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc63YAwBC-kZHbXKScgs-VbwtStdwl6dj8eSbsOS7WF-uTWLg/viewform) and supply your API key so that we can diagnose your bot.

Comment: Hello Sean,
Thank you for your answer :)
I actually got that data 2h hours after creating that thread so problem is solved thank you ;)

Thank you for making clearer the separator :)

Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a valid response for this post, then you should be successfully pushing data into your Chatbase. I've found that to be the most reliable check of valid POSTs. To answer your problem, I believe the session flow tab won't show anything until it collects 30 days of data. If you see your data generating in the other sections, just wait for the first 30 days of collection.

Comment: uff 30 days is pretty long to make sure everything works before deploying to production.
Did i miss anything on the documentation about those 30 days delay? I only read about a 6h delay  here and there.

I'll wait some weeks before checking again then !
Thank you for your answer !

Comment: For messages sent to Chatbase, there is a 1 hour processing interval. 
Message sessionization is performed on a 6 hour interval, which is the longest amount of time you would typically need to wait to see your latest messages reflected in session flow.  We identified an issue that caused some batches of new messages to not be processed for the Session Flow report, which was handled by manually reprocessing the records.

Answer (score 0):

And of course i just had to ask for the session flow tab to show my data :D

If anyone read this, i had to wait about a week before my session flows actually appear.

Problem solved !